# Better Way Without Goto?

Tags: c, goto

I have a program where my code uses a goto statement, and I want to get rid of it in a nice way, but I can't seem to find a solution.  If goto is the best way, then please let me know.  Here is a summary of the code:

```
//Counts how many times every word appears in a file
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUMWORDS 1000
#define WORDLEN 50

typedef struct
{
  char word[WORDLEN + 1];
  int num;
} Appearance;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *readfile;
  Appearance *appearlist[NUMWORDS] = {NULL};
  char word[WORDLEN + 1];
  int i;
  //Get a valid filename and open the file, store pointer into readfile
  ...

  char c;

  while (c != EOF) {
    skip:  //Annoying label
    //Get a word from readfile, store into word
    ...

    if (word[0] != '\0') {
      for (i = 0; i < NUMWORDS && appearlist[i]; i++) {
        if (strcmp(appearlist[i] -> word, word) == 0) {
          appearlist[i] -> num++;
          goto skip; //Annoying goto
        }
      }
      appearlist[i] = (Appearance *) malloc(sizeof(Appearance));
      appearlist[i] -> num = 1;
      strcpy(appearlist[i] -> word, word);
    }
  }

  //Display results, free memory
  ...

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is, I want to skip code that is outside of the loop I want to skip from.  I would like to not create another variable only designed for this.  If you want the full code, click on "Show code snippet."

```html
//Counts how many times every word appears in a file
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUMWORDS 1000
#define WORDLEN 50
#define FILENAMELEN 50

typedef struct
{
  char word[WORDLEN + 1];
  int num;
} Appearance;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char filename[FILENAMELEN];
  FILE *readfile;
  Appearance *appearlist[NUMWORDS] = {NULL};
  char word[WORDLEN + 1];
  size_t ln;
  int i;

  if (argc == 2)
    strncpy(filename, argv[1], sizeof(filename));
  else {
    printf("Enter a filename to count appearances from, or just press enter to quit: ");
    fgets(filename, FILENAMELEN, stdin);
    ln = strlen(filename) - 1;
    if (filename[ln] == '\n')
      filename[ln] = '\0';
  }

  while((readfile = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
    if (filename[0] == '\0')
      return 0;
    printf("Invalid file! Please enter another filename, or just press enter to quit: ");
    fgets(filename, FILENAMELEN, stdin);
    ln = strlen(filename) - 1;
    if (filename[ln] == '\n') filename[ln] = '\0';
  }

  char c;

  while (c != EOF) {
    skip:
    for (i = 0; (c = getc(readfile)) != EOF && (isalnum(c) || c == '\''); i++) {
      if (i >= WORDLEN) {
        word[i] = '\0';
        printf("\nWarning: word too long (over %d characters), trimming to: %s\n", WORDLEN, word);
        while ((c = getc(readfile)) != EOF && (isalnum(c) || c == '\'')) ;
      } else {
        word[i] = tolower(c);
      }
    }
    word[i] = '\0';

    if (word[0] != '\0') {
      for (i = 0; i < NUMWORDS && appearlist[i]; i++) {
        if (strcmp(appearlist[i] -> word, word) == 0) {
          appearlist[i] -> num++;
          goto skip;
        }
      }
      appearlist[i] = (Appearance *) malloc(sizeof(Appearance));
      appearlist[i] -> num = 1;
      strcpy(appearlist[i] -> word, word);
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < NUMWORDS && appearlist[i]; i++) {
    printf("Word: %s, Appearances: %d\n", appearlist[i] -> word, appearlist[i] -> num);
    free(appearlist[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have *undefined behavior* in your code. The value of uninitialized local non-static variables, like your variable `c`, is *indeterminate*, using such a variable without initializing it first leads to said undefined behavior.

Comment: SO is no code review site. If your code is correct, try at code review, but read their FAQ first!

Comment: `char c;  while (c != EOF) {`  --> What might happen on the first compare in `while()` with an uninitialized `c`?

Comment: While valid syntax, `appearlist[i] -> num` is quite uncommon and harder to read. You should not use spaces between the derefence-, arrow-, address- and member operators.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

Using `goto` in this case is often considered acceptable.

Alternatives would be to set a variable so that you can `continue` in the outer loop after `break`ing from the inner one, or turning the whole segment that you want to escape from into a separate function, and returning from it instead of using `goto`.

I'm ignoring any other issues there may be with the code that aren't relevant to the question!

Answer (score 1):

Put everything beginning with the 'if' statement into a separate method (let's call it "process" and replace the `goto` with `return`. Then the while-loop becomes:

```
  while (c != EOF) {
    //Get a word from readfile, store into word
    ...
    process(...);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using `goto` is a hint that code should use a helper function

```
static bool findword(Appearance *appearlist, size_t size, const char *word) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size && appearlist[i]; i++) {
    if (strcmp(appearlist[i]->word, word) == 0) {
      appearlist[i]->num++;
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}


while (c != EOF) {
  //Get a word from readfile, store into word
  ...
  if (word[0] != '\0') {
    if (findword(appearlist, NUMWORDS, word)) {
      continue;
    }
    appearlist[i] = (Appearance *) malloc(sizeof(Appearance));
    appearlist[i] -> num = 1;
    strcpy(appearlist[i] -> word, word);
  }
}
```